# Knapsack budgetting

Tags: optimization, recreational-mathematics, linear-programming, operations-research

#### The problem

I have $1000 of money.
With it I can buy 3 items:

- Item 1 which costs 45 dollars.
- Item 2 which costs 75 dollars.
- Item 3 which costs 25 dollars.

I want to know the optimal amount of each item to buy to come as close as possible to the following statements :

- 75% of the money I spend has been allocated to Item 1
- 20% of the money I spend has been allocated to Item 2
- 5% of the money I spend has been allocated to Item 3

**There is one strong rule: As long as there is enough money left to buy one of the items, I have to continue buying.**

#### Example :

What I mean with 'as close as possible to the following statements'

**Solution 1:**

- 80% Item 1
- 20% Item 2
- 0% Item 3

*sum of percentage differences = (80-75) + (20-20) + (5-0) = 10%*

**Solution 2:**

- 90% Item 1
- 5% Item 2
- 5% Item 3

*sum of percentage differences = (90-75) + (20-5) + (5-5) = 30%*

**The better solution is Solution 1** (because 10% is a smaller percentage difference than 30%)

Comment: Did you mean for the desired allocations to add to more that $100\%$?

Comment: A fairly sensible guess might be to adjust the percents so that they add to $100$, we get about $(71.43,23.8,4.76)$ try to do that exactly and adjust for integrality.  Barring arithmetic error that ends up at $(16,3,2)$ items or $(72.5,22.5,5)$ as cash allocation.  Not bad.  Not entirely sure it is optimal, but I bet it is close.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake with my percentages. It should be 75%, 20% and 5%. Edited the question

Comment: Ok.  Then, of course, you can skip the rescaling step in my calculation.  I note that the solution I got (with the slightly incorrect percentages) still looks pretty good here, but it's not so clearly unique.  I suggest searching around that point to see if there's a better choice.

Comment: FYI, in case knowing the terminology helps you find solutions: This is a type of [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: As a general remark:  Integer optimization is always tricky.  Especially when, as here, you don't expect to use all of the cash.  Given the very good solution I found, you can try to bound the various values (after all, if you are off by at least $5.5\%$ in any single slot then you can reject the point instantly).  that should get it down to a modest search.

Comment: Of course, if you could buy fractional items, then the optimum would be $(16.666666..., 2.666666..., 2)$.  So you should expect the answer to be close to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only bought Item 1, then you could buy $\lfloor \frac{1000}{45} \rfloor = 22$ of them.  Similarly, you could buy at most $\lfloor \frac{1000}{75} \rfloor = 13$ of Item 2, or $\lfloor \frac{1000}{25} \rfloor = 40$ of Item 3.  This gives us a maximum search space of $23 \times 14 \times 41 = 13202$ combinations (adding 1 to each factor because 0 is a valid quantity), amenable to brute-force search by computer.  So let's just do that.

```
ITEM1_PRICE = 45
ITEM2_PRICE = 75
ITEM3_PRICE = 25
MAX_TOTAL_PRICE = 1000
MIN_TOTAL_PRICE = MAX_TOTAL_PRICE - min(ITEM1_PRICE, ITEM2_PRICE, ITEM3_PRICE)
ITEM1_BUDGET_PROP = 0.75
ITEM2_BUDGET_PROP = 0.20
ITEM3_BUDGET_PROP = 0.05

# Store solutions in a list in case there's a tie
best_solutions = []
best_error = float('inf')

for qty1 in range(MAX_TOTAL_PRICE // ITEM1_PRICE + 1):
    for qty2 in range(MAX_TOTAL_PRICE // ITEM2_PRICE + 1):
        for qty3 in range(MAX_TOTAL_PRICE // ITEM3_PRICE + 1):
            price1 = qty1 * ITEM1_PRICE
            price2 = qty2 * ITEM2_PRICE
            price3 = qty3 * ITEM3_PRICE
            total_price = price1 + price2 + price3
            if MIN_TOTAL_PRICE <= total_price <= MAX_TOTAL_PRICE:
                prop1 = price1 / MAX_TOTAL_PRICE
                prop2 = price2 / MAX_TOTAL_PRICE
                prop3 = price3 / MAX_TOTAL_PRICE
                error = abs(prop1 - ITEM1_BUDGET_PROP) + abs(prop2 - ITEM2_BUDGET_PROP) + abs(prop3 - ITEM3_BUDGET_PROP)
                if error < best_error:
                    best_solutions = [(qty1, qty2, qty3)]
                    best_error = error
                elif error == best_error:
                    best_solutions.append((qty1, qty2, qty3))

print(best_solutions)
```

Running the program shows a unique optimal solution of $(16, 3, 2)$, i.e.:

- 16 units of Item 1 @ \$45, for a total price of \$720 (versus ideal \$750).
- 3 units of Item 2 @ \$75, for a total price of \$225 (versus ideal \$200).
- 2 units of Item 3 @ \$25, for a total price of \$50 (exactly the ideal amount).
- \$5 left over that's too small to buy anything with.